# Counting number of items of a list in XQuery

Tags: xquery

If I am given a list in XQuery, like: `1, 1, 2`

How do I count the number of instances of `1`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is actually a sequence and you can `count()` it...

```
let $sequence := ('1','1','2')
return
    count($sequence[.='1'])
```

produces:

`2`

Comment: I was struggling so much with this... I should have put this is for homework but I thought this would be the easier part, well it was but getting the list itself was hard :P